# PHP reading RSS feed gets error on the third link in a node

Tags: php, xml, rss

I am reading a RSS feed and each node has 3 links:

```html
<link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2202110476673931679/6339893542751280730/comments/default/1280042367141045524'/>

<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2202110476673931679/6339893542751280730/comments/default/1280042367141045524'/>

<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://misterika.blogspot.com/2016/04/blog-post_11.html?showComment=1460801110852#c1280042367141045524' title=''/>
```

I read the "href" attribute with this:

```html
'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')
```

There is no problem when I use item(0) for the first link, there is no problem when I use item(1) for the second link but when I use item(2) for the third link I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object

Any idea how can I solve it?

Here is my full code:

```
<?php
$rss = new DOMDocument();

$rss->load('http://misterika.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default');

$feed = array();
foreach ($rss->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
    $item = array ( 
        'title' => $node->getElementsByTagName('name')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'desc' => $node->getElementsByTagName('content')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link' => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(2)->getAttribute('href'),
        'date' => $node->getElementsByTagName('published')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        );
    array_push($feed, $item);
}
$limit = 5;
for($x=0;$x<$limit;$x++) {
    $title = str_replace(' & ', ' &amp; ', $feed[$x]['title']);
    $link = $feed[$x]['link'];
    $description = $feed[$x]['desc'];
    $date = date('l F d, Y', strtotime($feed[$x]['date']));
    echo '<p><strong><a href="'.$link.'" title="'.$title.'">'.$title.'</a></strong><br />';
    echo '<small><em>Posted on '.$date.'</em></small></p>';
    echo '<p>'.$link.'</p>';
    echo '<p>'.$description.'</p>';
}
```

?>

Comment: That means there is no 3rd link in the DOM under the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Working when I tested with the below sample snippet.

```
<?php

$xml = "<root><entry><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2202110476673931679/6339893542751280730/comments/default/1280042367141045524'/>

<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.blogger.com/feeds/2202110476673931679/6339893542751280730/comments/default/1280042367141045524'/>

<link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://misterika.blogspot.com/2016/04/blog-post_11.html?showComment=1460801110852#c1280042367141045524' title=''/></entry>

<entry><link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://google.com/'/>

<link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://jenson.in/'/></entry></root>";

$node = new DOMDocument;
$node->loadXML($xml);

foreach($node->getElementsByTagName("entry") as $entry)
{
    $link = $entry->getElementsByTagName("link");

    echo $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->getAttribute('href')."<br/>";
    echo $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(1)->getAttribute('href')."<br/>";
   //Below code checks if third link exists or not.
   echo ($link->length > 2)?$node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(2)->getAttribute('href'):"No alternate link!"."<br/>";
}   
?>
```

**[See Demo](http://ideone.com/e4YWyb)**

**UPDATE:**

In your Feed XML, There is no 3rd link after `http://misterika.blogspot.com/2016/03/blog-post_20.html?showComment=1462627509971#c2966841279736454385` Only 2 links available in that `entry` node. That's why you're getting error.

Comment: This code works but it still does not help me with this strange feed. I included all my code in my original post.

Comment: @Georgi.Bonchev There is no 3rd link available for One or more `entry` node which is why you're getting error. Check Updated answer.

Comment: Well, thanks but this is not the answer. Each <entry> tag has 3 link elements - link rel='edit', link rel='self', link rel='alternate'. I need to access the 3rd link.

Comment: @Georgi.Bonchev Check your `xml` code here http://pastebin.com/Bu0AG0Zq Search for content `Този коментар бе премахнат от автора` I didn't find any `alternate` link under that `entry` node.

Comment: I get it - there is one <entry> tag that does not have 3rd link and the whole script fails. I still need the 3rd link in other tags that are ok. What is the solution? How can I check if an <entry> tag has 3rd link or not?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
After looking at the URL you provided I made adjustments to the code using [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$rss = file_get_contents('http://misterika.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default');

$doc->loadXML($rss);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$xpath->registerNameSpace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');

$links = $xpath->query('/atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:link[@href]');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    $node = $link->nodeName;
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');

    echo "{$node} - {$href}\n";
}
```

The key here is to register the default namespace in order for the code to work.

Comment: The feed I ame reading is here: http://misterika.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default I am trying ro make it run with this code but still have troubles.

Comment: @Georgi.Bonchev The URL makes it clearer, I made adjustments to the code.

Comment: It looks like it might solve the problem. Very helpful code.